# How to make a linq Sum return null if the summed values are all null

Tags: linq, sum, nullable

I have a LINQ query that looks like this...

```
var duration = Level3Data.AsQueryable().Sum(d => d.DurationMonths);
```

If all the `d.DurationMonths` values are null the Sum returns `0`. How can I make the Sum return `null` if all the `d.DurationMonths` are `null`? Or do I need to run a separate query first to eliminate this situation before performing the sum?

Comment: What's the type of DurationMonths ? int ? `Nullable<int>` ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Along with the previous suggestion for an extension method - you could use a ternary operator...

```
var duration = Level3Data.AsQueryable().Any(d => d.DurationMonths.HasValue) 
               ? Level3Data.AsQueryable().Sum(d => d.DurationMonths) 
               : null;
```

Comment: Although this does enumerate the results twice, My collections are small and I find this the most readable. So Have accepted it. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `Aggregate` to provide custom aggregation code :

```
var items = Level3Data.AsQueryable();
var duration = items.Aggregate<D,int?>(null, (s, d) => (s == null) ? d.DurationMonths : s + (d.DurationMonths ?? 0));
```

(assuming the items in `Level3Data` are of type `D`)

Comment: The `+=` should really be just `+`.

Answer (score 3):

```
var outputIndicatorSum = (from OutputIndicatorTable in objDataBaseContext.Output_Indicators
                                          where OutputIndicatorTable.Output_Id == outputId
                                          select (int?)OutputIndicatorTable.Status).Sum();
                int outputIndicatorSumReturn = Convert.ToInt32(outputIndicatorSum);
                return outputIndicatorSumReturn;
```

You can explicitly type cast non-nullable varaible into nullable type.
`i.e, select (int?)OutputIndicatorTable.Status).Sum();`

Comment: This answer is wrong. Casting to `(int?)` before summing makes sense in the context of Linq2Sql, where `Sum` can return `null` (directly from the SQL query) even when the compiler infers non-nullable result which leads to an exception. With Linq2Objects, `Sum` always returns `0` even if all input elements were `null` or there were no input elements at all.

Answer (score 1):

Using Sum alone, this is impossible. As you indicated in your question, you will need to check for this situation before you call Sum:

```
var q = Level3Data.AsQueryable();
var duration = q.All(d => d.DurationMonths == null)
                   ? null
                   : q.Sum(d => d.DurationMonths);
```

Comment: Bah, less than a minute too late. Lol

Answer (score -1):

If you would like the result without two queries try:

var duration = Level3Data.AsQueryable().Sum(d => (double?)d.DurationMonths);

If you want zero instead of null as the result of this query use:

var duration = Level3Data.AsQueryable().Sum(d => (double?)d.DurationMonths) ?? 0;

Comment: I personally like this option the most.

Comment: If [`DurationMonths` is `int?`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1322544/how-to-make-a-linq-sum-return-null-if-the-summed-values-are-all-null#comment1156228_1322544) and all values are `null`, Linq2Sql will return `null` for `Sum`, and Linq2Objects will return `0`. The OP has the `0` returned, so they are using Linq2Objects, in which case casting to `double?` before summing [will not work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1322544/how-to-make-a-linq-sum-return-null-if-the-summed-values-are-all-null#comment69281108_16441725) and the result will still be `0`.